# How to mitigate increased AWS billing due to CloudWatch alarms (AWS Amplify)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

A few months ago, we noticed a significant increase in our monthly AWS billing, even though we hadn't made any significant changes to our infrastructure. After some investigation, we discovered that the charges were primarily coming from CloudWatch alarms, specifically "AlarmMonitorUsage (Alarms)," and it appears that multiple alarms are being created for each API in our AWS Amplify-powered mobile app.

I attempted to disable these alarms, assuming it would lower our costs, but I'm still seeing the charges persist, or the alarms may not be properly disabling. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? I would appreciate any insights or recommended solutions to address this billing problem without resorting to deleting the alarms entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe disabling cloud watch alarms will only turn them off temporarily. Have you tried just deleting the alarms all together? I'm trying to spin up an amplify project to get you a better answer.

Edit: Having it running, when you go to the amplify console and click on monitoring what do you see under the alarms tab?

Comment: I believe disabling cloud watch alarms will only turn them off temporarily. Have you tried just deleting the alarms all together? I'm trying to spin up an amplify project to get you a better answer.
- No not yet. I might want them at some point in the future.


Edit: Having it running, when you go to the amplify console and click on monitoring what do you see under the alarms tab?
- I don't see monitoring in the amplify console.

Comment: When you go to the Amplify console and click on the problem there should be a section labeled "Monitoring" in the menu on the left. It may be hidden so I would look for the hamburger menu icon in the top left